# General formula for partial sums

Tags: calculus

In my textbook, it states that the general formula for the partial sum

$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

My question is, if I have the following sum instead:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2}$$

Can I just flip the general formula to get this:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i^2} = \frac{6}{n(n+1)(2n+1)} $$

Or does it not work like that? Thank you!

Comment: Not a chance. It's not even true for $n=2$.

Comment: (aaaaand, you're starting the sum with $\frac1{0^2}$ )

Comment: Right! Thanks, I'll change that.

Comment: Does $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{2+3}$?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

Even with *just* two terms:
$$
\frac1a+\frac1b \neq \frac1{a+b},
$$ for example
$$
\frac11+\frac11=2 \neq \frac1{2}=\frac1{1+1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The way you are saying it, I remembered the mistake I often used to do when I was in fifth standerd. I used to convert $\frac{1}{\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}}=a+b$. That is what you are doing here. Just take deep breath and look at what you have written make sense or not.

Answer (score 1):

As $n$ increases, both sums increase. So it is not possible for the sums to be inverses.